# A shortcut for solving $\int \frac{dx}{(\sin x+\cos x)^3}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

So I'm trying to do an integral 
$$\int \frac{dx}{(\sin x +\cos x)^3}$$

This of course can be written as :

$$\int \frac{dx}{(\sin x+\cos x)(1+2\sin x\cos x)}$$

If now I use the tangent half-angle substitution, we get:

$$\int \frac{2(t^4+2t^2+1)\, dt}{(-t^2+2t+1)(t^4-4t^3+2t^2+4t+1)}=\int \frac{2(t^4+2t^2+1) \,dt}{(-t^2+2t+1)(t^2-2t-1)^2}$$

Which can be done by using partial fraction, but that  seems to be a lengthy process. I also tried deviding each term in denominator with $cosx$ so that i would get $\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ (derivative of $\tan x$) which got me in an even worse position than the partial fractions solution. I have a feeling there might be a *shortcut* for solving this, which is based on some trigonometric identity, but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: Write it in the form $R\sin (x + a)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $\sin(x) + \cos(x) = \sqrt{2} \sin(x + \pi/4)$.  Make an appropriate substitution to end up with a multiple of
$$
\int \csc^3(u)\,du
$$

Comment: In order to find substitutions like this in general, you should know about the [sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities).

Comment: It's situations like that make me love doing these problems. I spent an hour doing various recombinations of terms and couldn't get anything. I completely forgot about sum-to-product identities. I feel like an idiot :) Thank you.